# Unexpected token: io.listen(server)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets, websocket

I am new to `node.js`. Following some of the tutorials, I created a file named `server.js` and put this code in that file:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log('Connection');
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
 console.log(path);
    switch(path){
        case '/':
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write('hello world');
            break;
        case '/socket.html':
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write('Inside hello world');
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
                if (error){
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 403");
                }
                else{
                    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    response.write(data, "utf8");
                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 405");
            break;
    }
    response.end();
});

server.listen(8001);

var io.listen(server);
```

Then I run this using the command: `node C:\Users\user\Desktop\server.js` and I get this error:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\server.js:38
var io.listen(server);
  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
```

This line is causing the error:

`var io.listen(server);`

Initially I thought of installing the `npm` package `socket.io` hence I tried this:

`npm install --save socket.io`

But after this also I am getting the same error:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\server.js:38
var io.listen(server);
  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
```

Please advice how to resolve this error.

Comment: Why are you saying `var` and then not declaring a variable?

Comment: Even if I remove `var`, I am getting the error: `io.listen(server);
ReferenceError: io is not defined`

Comment: So require it before you use it: `var io = require('socket.io');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `var` keyword is used to declare a variable. I suspect you're missing the variable name:

```
var foo = io.listen(server);
```

Other that that, there's no `io` anywhere else in your code. Are you missing a require call?

---

The *socket.io* library is apparently not bundled:

```
C:\>node
> require("socket.io");
Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at repl:1:1
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at repl.js:249:20
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

[Installation](http://socket.io/download/) though is a one liner:

```
npm install socket.io
```

Comment: In this case I am getting the error: `var foo = io.listen(server);
    
ReferenceError: io is not defined`

Comment: Sure, `io` is definitively not defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: yes correct. Since I dont have any idea about node.js, I blindly followed this link: http://danielnill.com/nodejs-tutorial-with-socketio/. Can you please suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: Just look at answer by Sterling Archer.

Comment: Yep, that blog has the two important typos we've highlighted.

Comment: ok I got it...Thanks for your inputs. So, In this case no need to install the `npm install --save socket.io` command right? Please confirm whether I need or not so that I can close off this thread. I guess I need to install the `socket.io`

Comment: You still need to install the module, otherwise the require statement will not find it and you'll get another error.

Answer (score 3):

```
var io.listen(server);
```

By using the keyword `var` it expects an assignment statement or declaration, and you're trying to use a method call as a variable name basically.

As for removing it, you'll get a io is not defined error because it looks like you're not calling the module.

```
var io = require("socket.io");
```